# C# - Serial Data Send To Active Window with Windows Service

Tags: c#, winapi, sendmessage

Data is being received by USB serial communication.

I decided to parse the received data and throw a value by calling SendMessage in the currently active window to give the same effect as keyboard input.

It worked normally in the console, but there was a problem when implementing this function as a Window Service.

Upon checking, the Window Service says that it cannot access the UI of the logged-on session.

Is there any way I can implement a window service that can produce the same effect as keyboard input?

I want to make a Window Service to receive RF wireless keyboard signals through USB Serial and deliver them to the system.

Comment: Two articles that my be of relevance here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513 and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/51399b53-6ecc-4215-a1ce-5db59e92274a/calling-sendinput-from-a-windows-service?forum=windowssdk

Comment: Is it close to impossible as a result?

Comment: You can write a service that communicate with a program running in user session using a different communication way than windows/messages. In a standard Windows, there are many programs ran at user's login. Autoruns gives a list of the ones running on your machine https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: If you don't want to display a UI maybe "[A message-only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows)" help. It enables you to send and receive messages. It is not visible, has no z-order, cannot be enumerated, and does not receive broadcast messages. The window simply dispatches messages.